# React Context consumer can't find props

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I'm trying to use React Context API to pass props, however I got "undefined" error. The version of react is 16.3.2, and react-dom version is 16.3.2. The following is my code:

Provider.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';

export const PathContext = React.createContext({
  rootPath: "http://localhost/example"
});
```

App.jsx:

```
import React from 'react';
import {PathContext} from './Provider.jsx';

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <PathContext.Provider>
          <AppRootPath />
        </PathContext.Provider>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class AppRootPath extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <span>App Root Path</span><br />
        <PathContext.Consumer>
          {
            ({rootPath}) => <span>{rootPath}</span>
          }
        </PathContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
export default App;
```

I can't find any problems in here, but the console reports this error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'rootPath' of undefined`, and the error happens in here: `({rootPath}) => <span>{rootPath}</span>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

About using a [default value](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#consumer):

> If there is no **Provider** for this context above, the value argument
>   will be equal to the defaultValue that was passed to createContext().

But you are wrapping it with Provider. Try removing Provider:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <AppRootPath />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class AppRootPath extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <span>App Root Path</span><br />
        <PathContext.Consumer>
          {
            ({rootPath}) => <span>{rootPath}</span>
          }
        </PathContext.Consumer>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```